# Redux testing: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: redux, jestjs, enzyme, sinon

I have a `Redux` app and it is working perfectly without any errors. Now I am trying to test it with `Enzyme`, `Jest` and `Sinon`:

```
  it('calls constructor', () => {
    sinon.spy(SavedVariantsComponent.prototype, 'constructor')
    const store = configureStore()(STATE1)
    wrapper = mount(<SavedVariantsComponent store={store} match={{ params: {} }} />)
    expect(SavedVariantsComponent.prototype.constructor).toHaveProperty('callCount', 1)
  })
```

In `SavedVariantsComponent` I have `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onSubmit: (updates) => {
      dispatch(updateSavedVariantTable(updates))
      const { match, analysisGroup } = ownProps
      const { familyGuid, variantGuid, tagArray, gene } = match.params
      const familyGuids = familyGuid ? [familyGuid] : (analysisGroup || {}).familyGuids
      const combineVariants = /combined_variants/.test(match.url)
      dispatch(loadSavedVariants(combineVariants, familyGuids, variantGuid, tagArray, gene))
    },  
    loadSavedVariants: (...args) => dispatch(loadSavedVariants(...args)),
  }
}
```

And `loadSavedVariants` look like that:

```
export const loadSavedVariants = (combineVariants, familyGuids, variantGuid, tagArray, gene = '') => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
...
...
```

and the error while running `jest` is:

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Which makes an `HTTP Request` that may not work in the current case. How to fix this error? I need to test that the constructor was called, but later on will also need to see how the inner `Components` are rendered, so need to have `mount` there. I suppose I am doing something wrong in testing and not in the real code since the latter is working without any errors, warnings or issues.

Comment: What does `configureStore` look like? Does it setup thunk middleware?

Comment: It is just: `import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'`

Comment: That's probably why. You need to setup thunk to be able to use thunk middleware.

Comment: You mean in tests? In the actual code things are working perfectly, no warnings, no errors... If in tests, how would you do that correctly?

Comment: I left how as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to configure your mock store to work with redux-thunk. See: https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store#asynchronous-actions

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const middlewares = [thunk] // add your middlewares like `redux-thunk`
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares)
```